# Type mismatch error in on worksheets.range

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am making a VBA machine that takes a Word document and searches it for terms in an Excel file, then copies each sentence with the term and pastes it in the Excel sheet. I have kind of cobbled together two different pieces of code that search a Word document for a list of words from another Word document, and one that copies every sentence that uses a given word. Here is my code:

```
Sub thesearchmacro()
 Dim excelfile As Object
 Dim excelsheet As Object
 Dim worddoc As Document
 Dim searchcell As Range
 Dim destcol As Integer
 Dim destrow As Integer
 Dim searchterms As Range
 Dim documentrange As Range



 Set documentrange = ActiveDocument.Range
 Set excelfile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set excelsheet = excelfile.workbooks.Open("U:\filepath\searchmachine.xlsm")
 Set searchterms = excelsheet.Worksheets("Data").Range("B2:GX2")
 destcol = 2
 For Each searchcell In searchterms.Cells

    destrow = 3
    With documentrange.Find
        Do
            .Text = searchcell
            documentrange.Expand unit:=wdSentence
            documentrange.Copy
            documentrange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            excelsheet.Cells(destrow, destcol).Paste
            destrow = destrow + 1


    Loop While .Found
    destcol = destcol + 1
 End With
 Next

End Sub
```

Whenever I run this:

```
   Set searchterms = excelsheet.Worksheets("Data").Range("B2:GX2")
```

comes back with a type mismatch error.

*edit: missed a copy

added findwindow's suggestion

This is what worked in the end. If you are trying to replicate it feel free to ask me anything.

```
 Sub thesearchmacro()
  Dim excelfile As Object
  Dim excelsheet As Object
  Dim worddoc As Document
  Dim searchcell As Object
  Dim destcol As Integer
  Dim destrow As Integer
  Dim destcell as Object
  Dim searchterms As Object
 Dim documentrange As Range



 Set documentrange = ActiveDocument.Range
 Set excelfile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set excelsheet = excelfile.workbooks.Open("U:\filepath\searchmachine.xlsm")
 Set searchterms = excelsheet.Worksheets("Data").Range("B2:GX2")
 destcol = 2
 For Each searchcell In searchterms.Cells

    destrow = 3
    With documentrange.Find
        Do
            .Text = searchcell
            .execute

           If .Found Then
            documentrange.Expand unit:=wdSentence
            excelsheet.Sheets("Data").Cells(destrow, destcol) = documentrange
            documentrange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

            destrow = destrow + 1


    Loop While .Found
    destcol = destcol + 1
 End With
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `set` infront.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried that and I still go the same error.

Comment: What happens when you `Dim excelsheet as Workbook` rather than as `Object`?

Comment: "User-Defined type not defined" on workbook

Comment: The code is written to be run through the word file. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Word.Range` and `Excel.Range` are different types.

If you are happy to add a reference to Excel to your project, do that and replace all `Range`s with either `Word.Range` or `Excel.Range` as appropriate.
Otherwise declare all Excel types as `Object`s.

Comment: Replacing relevant range tags with object tags seemed to work. Thank you!